# Can't get TextInput value in react native

Tags: react-native

Hi friends I hope you are doing very well ^^
I am struggling to get a TextInput value when a user enters it in a simple basic form I've created, here is the field :

```
<TextInput placeholder='latitude' name='lat'/>
<Button style={styles.signIn}
    title="Show my entered text"
      onPress={() => {
      alert(this.state.lat)}}
  />
```

I tried so many methods to get the value of this field but unfortunately none works.. I am new to react native so I really don't know how can this be done properly (is there any variable I need to define) because in javascript I used to get it only by the GetElementById quite simple right XD
I tried creating a variable exactly bellow the imports like this :

```
value={this.state.lat}
```

So I can get the above textInput actual value entered by the user but it isn't working at all and my alert function is not returning anything (I actually don't know if alert() is a react native integrated function or I need to define it from scratch :/), please help I am really lost I tried many solutions on the web but nothing resolves my problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = { lat: "" };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="latitude"
          name="lat"
          value={this.state.lat}
          onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ lat: text })}
        />
        <Button
          style={styles.signIn}
          title="Show my entered text"
          onPress={() => {
            alert(this.state.lat);
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```